# How can I visualize a dataset containing 5 independent and 1 dependent variable?

Tags: python, visualization

I have a DataFrame containing 576 rows with these variables, where the first 5 is the independent variable and the last is the dependent one. The line below shows the range of the variables. I am looking for an effective way to visualize the dataset. I want to show the optimum fitness value for the 5 variables.

The range of the variables:
`α=[0.4, 0.7] c1=[1, 2] c2=[1, 2] ww=[0.6, 1.25] p_rate=[0.05, 0.3] fitness =[1000,10000]`

I would be grateful if anyone could help me with this visualization. Thank you

I tried this method but the result is very hard to understand.

https://github.com/ostwalprasad/PythonMultiDimensionalPlots/blob/master/src/6D.py

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend parallel coordinates, plotly has a good implementation [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2FEx.png).

https://plotly.com/python/parallel-coordinates-plot/

[image]